# How to display different date formats in Odoo datetime fields?

Tags: python, datetime, odoo, odoo-11

Currently the date format on our Odoo CRM looks like `11/20/2017 13:03:41` but I want to display the format to `July 3rd 3:00PM` and on another place show as `3 Jul 3:00PM`

We show this field in the form

```xml
<field name="pickup_time"/>
```

I have searched a lot to find how to change the format, but It's mainly to change in the local settings and it's permanently one setting for everywhere. Which would not solve of what we want, like having two different format for different places.

Comment: You can create a computed field with the format that you want

Comment: computed field? via coding? is there any sample if its via coding...

Comment: Yes, you need to declare it in python. Check the Odoo documentation

Comment: If I have time I will write an answer with the code

Comment: @ChesuCR — OK thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Along Odoo the default constant date format used is `DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT`. This is defined in the file  `misc.py`

```py
DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d"
DEFAULT_SERVER_TIME_FORMAT = "%H:%M:%S"
DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT = "%s %s" % (
    DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT,
    DEFAULT_SERVER_TIME_FORMAT)
```

So if you declare the field like the following code then that constant is going to be used:

```py
pickup_time = fields.Datetime(
    string="Pickup time",
)
```

So if you want to use another format you can create a computed field with that custom format. You need to use some date functions: `strftime` (object to string) and `strptime` (string to object). The formats codes are explained almost at the bottom of [this python documentation page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

```py
from datetime import datetime
from odoo.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT

[...]

pickup_time_formated = fields.Char(   # it is going to be a readonly field
    string='Pickup time formated',
    compute='_compute_pickup_time_formated'
)

@api.multi
@api.depends('pickup_time')
def _compute_pickup_time_formated(self):
    for record in self:
        date = record.pickup_time
        date_obj = datetime.strptime(date, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)   # to convert it in a date object

        v = date_obj.day % 10           # to get the remainder of the operation
        if v == 1:
            ordinal_suffix = 'st'
        elif v == 2:
            ordinal_suffix = 'nd'
        elif v == 3:
            ordinal_suffix = 'rd'
        else:
            ordinal_suffix = 'th'

        # format 'July 3rd 3:00PM'
        record.pickup_time_formated = datetime.strftime(date_obj, '%B %d' + ordinal_suffix + ' %I:%M %p')

        # format '3 Jul 3:00PM'
        # record.pickup_time_formated = datetime.strftime(date_obj, '%d %b %I:%M %p'),
```

And then you can show the new fields in the xml form:

```xml
<field name="pickup_time_formated"/>
```

Comment: This much? There is no way to pass the format option to the field widget?

Comment: I don't think so @mangatinanda, at least at the time I wrote the answer. If you find a better way let me know